# Linq for list of objects make a collection of its fields

Tags: c#, linq

Can LINQ write this shorter?

```
class MyClass
{
    public int Field1;
    public int Field2;
}

var src = new List<MyClass>
{
    new MyClass{Field1 = 0, Field2 = 1},
    new MyClass{Field1 = 2, Field2 = 3}
};

var list = new List<int>();
foreach (var item in src)
{
    list.Add(item.Field1);
    list.Add(item.Field2);
}
```

In the end, `list` is like this: 0, 1, 2, 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can put the `int` values into an array and use `SelectMany` to flatten the arrays:

```
var list = src.SelectMany(x => new[] { x.Field1, x.Field2 }).ToList();
```

For completion, if you want to do this for *all* public `int` fields in your class without having to manually specify them, you may use reflection for that:

```
var fields = typeof(MyClass).GetFields().Where(f => f.FieldType == typeof(int));
var list = src.SelectMany(x => fields.Select(f => (int)f.GetValue(x))).ToList();
```